# VBA Clustered columns graph

Tags: vba, excel, graph

[image: vba graph]

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to write a VBA code to write a chart similar to the one in the image. (What is shown would be sufficient; a couple "nice to haves" are below).

I have used the macro recorder and changed it a little bit to come up with this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$i$13")
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft -111
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop 244.8
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").ScaleWidth 1.7225, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
```

This gets me everything I need, but also has other data that I don't need.
I need to have total cost only (not direct cost) and model cost only (no baseline)

I also tried adding each series one by one like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(202, xlColumnClustered).Select
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("D8:i8")
    .Name = ActiveSheet.Range("$d$9")
    .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("D11:i11")
End With
```

But that doesn't look at all like what I expected it to look like.

Now the nice-haves:
- would like to have the data labels written vertically, because I need to keep all 4 decimal places
- I don't need to have "model" written under each column; instead, would ike to have the Places written there in an angle
- in the legend "Total cost" is shown next to each place; would be better to put it in the title once.

Any directional guidance on how how I should approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your specific question? This is not a forum where you provide a list of requirements and expect others to solve your problems for free...

Comment: David, I was looking for directional guidance - eg. should I look into adding each series one by one? Or should I create a "full" graph first, and then uncheck the series I don't need, like I would if I manually added the graph? I started learning VBA only a week ago, so I don't yet know what is possible and how I should think about something like this.

Comment: Try using the macro recorder and changing individual pieces of formatting that you don't like. For example just record changing the alignment of the data labels. Then figure out the property that relates to that and incorporate into your sub. Also review the Chart Class in Object Browser and get to know what properties are available.

Comment: Thanks, Stef. I tried recording a macro, and editing the graph to unselect the "model" series and select the "baseline" ones - it doesn't appear to record anything though, all I get is
Sub Macro2()    

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate


End Sub

Comment: For the most control, I like to add each series one-by-one. 1) Add the chart, 2) add each series and set their properties as needed.

Comment: Often it's better to set up a staging area in the worksheet which has only the data you need in the chart. So copy the data you want and paste special - link in its new location. You can copy paste in several operations, or use Ctrl-click to select multiple ranges, then copy and paste special - link. Then make your chart from this staging data. With no extraneous data in the range, your simple code for SetSourceData is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, this is what I came up with. It seems to be working fine.
The sub is called from another sub, and the inputs are the rows and columns of the data table.

Sub writegraph(startrow As Integer, lastrow As Integer, lastcol As Integer)

```
Range("A3").Select 'otherwise graph can give unpredictable results

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, g As Integer

Dim objCht As ChartObject

Dim graph(0 To 1) As String
Dim xval As Range
Dim val As Range

graph(0) = "BASELINE"
graph(1) = "MODEL"

'create x values = to each of the products
For j = 4 To lastcol - 1 Step 2
    If xval Is Nothing Then
        Set xval = ActiveSheet.Cells(startrow, j)
    Else
        Set xval = Application.Union(xval, ActiveSheet.Cells(startrow, j))
    End If
Next j

' create the graphs
For g = 0 To UBound(graph)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = graph(g) & " (Total cost)"
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = graph(g)

    'loop through each of the places
    For i = startrow + 2 To lastrow Step 2

        Set val = Nothing

        'loop through each of the products and set the values for the graph
        For j = 4 To lastcol - 1 Step 2
            If val Is Nothing Then
                Set val = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + g)
            Else
                Set val = Application.Union(val, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j + g))
            End If
        Next j

        'write the series for the graph
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = xval
            .Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
            .Values = val
            .ApplyDataLabels
            .DataLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
        End With

    Next i

    'show y axis labels
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisShow)
    'show legend. (ideally could show plant instead below each bar; not sure how to do that)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

    'reduce the hight of the bar, so the data labels fit
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    Selection.Height = 110
    Selection.Top = 60

    'add tick marks
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorTickMark = xlCross
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    'move the chart on the page
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(graph(g)).Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 2, 3).Left
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(graph(g)).Height = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lastrow + 2, 2), Cells(lastrow + 12, 2)).Height
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(graph(g)).Width = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(lastrow + 2, 3), Cells(lastrow + 2, lastcol)).Width

Next g

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("BASELINE").Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 2, 2).Top
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("MODEL").Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 14, 2).Top
```

End Sub